# Focus input on button click using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 collapse example code mostly.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <input type="text" name="test" id="test-id">
  </div>
</div>
```

There is a hidden div with an input field that reveals when you click the button, how can I focus the input when someone clicks on the button? using JS onlick seems to interrupt collapse ability from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the `jQuery` (`3.5.1` preferably) library before your `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` and use its `focus()` function within a `setTimeout()` function. This will focus on the `input` after a certain number of milliseconds of the button being clicked.

Here is a fiddle that shows it working (focusing after 1 second):

https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/z5wr96Lt/18/

Comment: Worked flawlessly!

Comment: @RicardoMehr Awesome, glad to help. You could probably move it down to a half of a second (`500` instead of `1000`). That might help the user even more.